# Delete Cell from UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cell

I am faced with a small problem. I have a UIButton on my cell in which when pressed I want the cell to be deleted. I have attempted this, but gives error.

```
- (IBAction)deleteCell:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MainViewController *view = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[view.nameArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[view.priceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[view.mainTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

I have a feeling I am not specifying the indexPath correctly, don't know how.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: What is the value for indexPath ? can you test if indexPath is valid then delete the row otherwise alert "Wrong selection"

Comment: Not by a computer at the moment, but something about declaring for a UIButton, which leads me to believe its about the indexPath.

Comment: Exactly, I don't know how to declare the indexPath for a cell from the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done like this. I have my own MyCustomCell class where I have button for each cell.

```
//MyCustomCell.h

@protocol MyCustomCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)deleteRecord:(UITableViewCell *)forSelectedCell;

@end

@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell {

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *deleteButton;
@property (unsafe_unretained) id<MyCustomCellDelegate> delegate;
@end

//MyCustomCell.m

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
     self.deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44)];
    [self.deleteButton setTitle:@"Delete your record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.deleteButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    [self.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editRecord:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
 }

-(IBAction)editRecord:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate deleteRecord:self]; // Need to implement whoever is adopting this protocol
}
```

--

```
// .h

@interface MyView : UIView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MyCustomCellDelegate> {


NSInteger rowOfTheCell;
```

**NOTE: Do not forget to set the delegate MyCustomCellDelegate to your cell.**

```
// .m

-(void)deleteRecord:(UITableViewCell*)cellSelected
{
     MyCustomCell *selectedCell = (MyCustomCell*)cellSelected;
     UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[selectedCell superview];
     NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:selectedCell]; //current indexPath
     rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];  // current selection row

     [view.nameArray removeObjectAtIndex:rowOfTheCell];
     [view.priceArray removeObjectAtIndex:rowOfTheCell];
     [view.mainTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pathOfTheCell]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass parameter as integer.

```
- (IBAction)deleteCell:(NSInteger)indexPath {
MainViewController *view = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[view.nameArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath];
[view.priceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath];
[view.mainTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This was the problem for him. He was not able to get the correct indexPath. Then how he will pass the integer value to your method.